# React element ref doesn't exist after API request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a "FileDownload" component that I am using to a trigger a form submit, thus prompting a download on the client. I have to first dispatch a redux action to get a new JWT token before I trigger the download to make sure that the user is authenticated. However, once I refresh the token, the element ref no longer exists.

**Does not work**

```
class FileDownload extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () => {

        console.log(this.refs);
        // => {fileDownload: form.file-download}

        this.props.refreshToken()
            .then(()=> {

                 console.log(this.refs);
                 // => {}

                 this.refs.fileDownload.submit();
                 // => Error: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
                <form
                    ref="fileDownload"
                    action={this.props.url}
                    className="file-download"
                    method="POST">
                    <input
                        disabled={this.props.disabled}
                        name="formData"
                        type="submit"
                        value={JSON.stringify(this.props.data)}
                    />
                </form>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

If I call `this.refs.fileDownload.submit()` *before* dispatching `refreshToken()`, the file downloads as expected...

**Works**

```
...
handleClick = () => {

    console.log(this.refs);
    // => {fileDownload: form.file-download}

    this.refs.fileDownload.submit(); // successfully downloads
}
...
```

---

**Update**

I've updated the code to use callback refs per React's recommendation, but am experiencing the same problem:

```
class FileDownload extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () => {

        this.props.refreshToken()
            .then(()=> {
                 this.form.submit();
            });
    }

    handleRef = (ref) => {
       if (ref) {
           this.form = ref;
       }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
                <form
                    ref="fileDownload"
                    action={this.props.url}
                    className="file-download"
                    method="POST">
                    <input
                        disabled={this.props.disabled}
                        name="formData"
                        type="submit"
                        value={JSON.stringify(this.props.data)}
                    />
                </form>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

*Screen Capture of behavior with `this.form.submit()` **inside** of the promise chain*
[image]

*Screen capture of behavior with `this.form.submit()` **outside** the promise chain*
[image]

---

Why isn't `this.refs.fileDownload` available after I call the `refreshToken()` action?

Comment: You actually submit the form, so the page is reloaded (or redirected to `this.props.url`) -- as it seems.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the form downloads correctly if I call `submit()` before I call `refreshToken()`...

Comment: Could it be that you're using an arrow function inside your component? Try it with `handleClick() { ...` syntax

Comment: Still doesn't work if I bind `handleClick` in the constructor

Comment: what happens if you do `handleClick = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

 // run rest of code. 
}

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Any chance you can post the code for refreshToken?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because when you use arrow functions, the `this` context is not passed along to the function. See [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

I would suggest you move the 'then' function out and binding this to it in the constructor.

```
class FileDownload extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.refreshTokenCallback = this.refreshTokenCallback.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  refreshTokenCallback() {
    this.refs.fileDownload.submit();
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.props.refreshToken().then(this.refreshTokenCallback);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Arrow functions do not create a `this` context, so `this` still refers to the component class. I indulged you by trying out your example, but it still does not work.

Comment: Then there is more to it than just the code you have here. You need to update your question with info about `refreshToken`. It seems it might be updating the redux state and causing your Component to re-render.

Comment: Also, you should not be using string refs. Instead use the ref callback `ref={(el) => { this.fileDownload = el; }} />`

Answer (score 0):

Your refs should be callback methods instead of strings. Use of strings are considered legacy and there are known issues with this pattern.

> If you worked with React before, you might be familiar with an older API where the ref attribute is a string, like "textInput", and the DOM node is accessed as this.refs.textInput. We advise against it because string refs have some issues, are considered legacy, and **are likely to be removed in one of the future releases**. If you're currently using this.refs.textInput to access refs, we recommend the callback pattern instead.
>   https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Thanks @Ray, that's a good point about callback refs. I've updated the example above to use callback refs instead of string refs, but still unable to call `submit()` inside the promise callback...